# Random (rare): MySQL Stored Procedure Does Not Exist

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that runs each day, for roughly 20 schemas (each have their own copy), for the last 3-4 months.

I got the error "Procedure [xxx] does not exist" for all databases in my report. They do exist, and they work correctly every time it's run. I just ran the cron job manually and it worked perfectly.

It's not a creation, implementation, network, or permissions issue, as it's been working for the past 3-4 months without problems. It's critical this stored procedure runs without fail.

Q: What can cause a Stored Procedure to "not exist" at random, or could some other factor be involved?

Comment: Check that user used for automated run can see and execute that SP.

Comment: They can. And they have been for the last 3-4 months.

Comment: You're saying: 1) SP ran for 3-4 months fine. 2) I am getting error.  - It is SP failing now or runs from time to time?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  Let's see the `CALL` statement.  Now, let's see what comes _before_ the `CALL`.

Comment: Do you have a cron job that `DROPs` and `reCREATEs` the SP?  When does it run?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to solve it?